# String and Comparable Interface

Tags: java

For a Java assignment I have to sort by length an `ArrayList<String>` using the `Comparable` interface.

What I have done, and it works, is to create a custom object in a class that implements `Comparable`and set the `CompareTo()` to use length.
It's ok and it works.

I was just wondering if there is an easier way.

I know that `String` in Java already implements `Comparable` interface.
But the natural order is lexicographic or alphabetic, not by length.
I have no idea how I can implement a different `CompareTo()` for instances of the class `String` without having to create my object.
Is there a way?
Or am I missing the logic?

(I cannot use `Comparator`, I have to use the `Comparable` interface.)

Comment: Curious.  Why couldn't you use a comparator?

Comment: university assignment unfortunately :/
I don't understand it either! All the example I could find where with comparator

Comment: That would be because a comparator is the easier way, but it sounds like the professor wants you to understand how overriding and interfaces works or something.

Comment: There are many easier ways, but it sounds like your professor won't let you use any of them.  Given the constraints of this assignment, I think what you've done is quite reasonable.

Comment: yeah :( so I guess the only way to implement Comparable is to create my class right? even if I am just using Strings?

Comment: Yes, `String` is final, so you can't subclass it; you *have* to create your own wrapper class.

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting frustrated with institutions that shoehorn their curriculum into ridiculous and entirely unrealistic constraints.

In *practice*, you are going to be using a `Comparator<String>` which allows you the flexibility to use lambdas to sort the results.  It's also incredibly terse, too.

On *principle*, what you've described is the only other logical approach.  The only way you could practically solve this is to create your own class that encapsulates the `String` instance that you want, and sort *that*.

Comment: I agree actually they just create confusion in the mind of people that are just starting to learn!!! Thanks a lot for the answers guys

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your wrapper object is the simplest way to meet the silly requirement. Just write a method that compares the lengths of the contained strings.

Comment: And possibly invokes `String.compareTo()` when the lengths are equal?

Comment: @Erick Not unless that was specified.